# Grails joining tables

Tags: grails, join, groovy, left-join, hql

I have two classes. For simplicity, I removed unrelated data. I need join Order to Survey not vice-versa. 
I know that I can run 
`select * from Order o right join order.survey s where s.id='x'` 
However, it is not what I would like to do.  I would like to join Order to Survey with left outer join, but the survey doesn't have an instance of Order class in the class. The order holds an instance of the survey class, that's why it is easier to join tables from order class. I did it using SQL in Grails, however I wonder how it can be done using hql. 
The sql code is as following.

```
Select survey.*,ao.* from survey sr left outer join order ao on ao.survey_id=sr.id
```

Models are as following

```
class Order{
 Survey survey
}

class   Survey {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sr, (SELECT ao FROM namespace.Order ao WHERE ao.survey = sr.id)
FROM namespace.Survey sr
```

You list all Survey objects and if exists an associated Order you'll get by subquery

**Pay attention:** I've add namespace term, you'll change with your namespace class

Comment: in this case you are selecting some datas from ao. In my case, I need to filter by some values  in ORDER, that's why I need to join tables and use it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do joins in HQL, you have to extend your domain model. Add a back-ref to your `Survey` class:

```
class Survey {
  static belongsTo = [ order:Order ]
}
```

so, you can resolve the `Order` instance from it:

```
Survey s = Survey.get someId
s.order
```

or

```
def orders = Survey.executeQuery 'select order from Survey where order.id = 111'
```

Comment: In your suggestion, I have to add order to Survey. However, it doesn't work for me. There shouldn't be order id in survey. If I add belongs to then it will add orderid column to Survey in the database. However, if you suggested using  "hasone" to Order, it could be better. However, in that case, I have to make order instance in Survey notNullable and it doesn't work for me either. Thanks anyway